# Accessing raw requests in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis, url-rewriting

I'm looking for a way to bypass all ASP.NET-specific behaviour, and work in a IIS/azure server like I would on most other servers (receive the request string, write the response). I understand this is not a common desire in ASP.NET, but this would be great to port some external code to work on ASP.NET.

So, basically I'm looking for a way that will:

- For each request that is not to a physical file, call my handler
- This handler will receive the raw HTTP request (it's ok for an abstraction of it, given that I have the same information)
- The web server logic will process the request and write the response (again, it's OK for an abstraction, given that I can write the same kind of information, like HTTP status and HTTP headers)

What's the best way to achieve this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write yourself a custom HTTP Module and register it with IIS.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673.aspx

Comment: Would this work with Azure servers as well? Also is there any common restriction for shared hosting services and HTTP modules? Thank you!

Comment: I imagine it would, haven't tested however, we have typically hosted on our own managed servers.  It's fairly easy to get a test DLL running in order to test, however.  The DLL ends up being standard CLR code that runs as the same permission of IIS.

Comment: Very nice!!! I'll leave this question open just so I can test it at Azure, but it seems a very good way to solve this! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

How about [NancyFx](http://nancyfx.org/)?

> Nancy is designed to handle DELETE, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, POST, PUT and
>   PATCH requests and provides a simple, elegant, Domain Specific
>   Language (DSL) for returning a response with just a couple of
>   keystrokes, leaving you with more time to focus on the important
>   bits.. your code and your application.

Comment: Wow! It looks awesome! Will check it out in more detail right now! Thanks!!

Comment: Though it looks awfully more complex than what I'd need. Looking here is kind of scary: https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/tree/master/src